# Unable to access user info object property - facebook chat api

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I'm using [Facebook chat api](https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api) to create a simple cli script that will reply to messages that are sent to my facebook account. I'm trying to assign and get the user name and my name to use them inside the reply but they are always undefined. I think that the object property aren't assigned correctly. Is there a fix for this?

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const fb = require('facebook-chat-api'); 
const path = require('path');
const appStateFile = path.format({ dir: __dirname, base: 'appstate.json' });
let currentUser = null;

if( !fs.existsSync(appStateFile) ){
    //debug .env
    console.log(process.env);

    fb({email: process.env.FB_EMAIL, password: process.env.FB_PWD}, (err, api) => {
        if(err){ 
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(api);
        api.setOptions({
            listenEvents: true
        });
        fs.writeFileSync(appStateFile, JSON.stringify(api.getAppState()));
        let id = api.getCurrentUserID();
        api.getUserInfo(id, (err, profile) => {
            console.log(profile); // profile is logged correctly
            currentUser = profile;
        });
        api.listenMqtt( (err, event) => {
            if(err){ 
                return console.log(err);
            }
            if(event.type === 'message'){
                console.log(event.body)
                api.getUserInfo(event.senderID, (err, user) => {
                    if(err){
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(user); // user object is logged correctly
                    api.sendMessage('...', event.threadID)
                });
            }
        });
    });
}else{
    fb({appState: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(appStateFile))}, (err, api) => {
        if(err){ 
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(api);
        api.setOptions({
            listenEvents: true
        });

        let id = api.getCurrentUserID();
        api.getUserInfo(id, (err, profile) => {
            console.log(profile);
            currentUser = profile;
        });
        api.listenMqtt( (err, event) => {
            if(err){ 
                return console.log(err);
            }
            if(event.type === 'message'){
                console.log(event.body)
                api.getUserInfo(event.senderID, (err, user) => {
                    if(err){
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(user)
                    api.sendMessage(`FB Pager v1.0.\nHi ${user.name}!Your message was forwarded with an email to ${currentUser.name}.`, event.threadID)
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can't undestand the question. Where is the code is your error happening? From your comments it looks like you are able to get the user.

Comment: @Mellet I only get the user object from the library, but it will be undefined if I try access the name property in this way `${user.name}` or `${currentUser.name}` !

Comment: Is it here you are having the error? ```api.sendMessage(`FB Pager v1.0.\nHi ${user.name}!Your message was forwarded with an email to ${currentUser.name}., event.threadID)``` What is currentUser and user when you log it out above?

Comment: yes, the problem is with that line. `user` is the object returned from the `getUserInfo` method callback and as writed in the documentations is supposed to have a `name` property. `currentUser` is supposed to contain my profile info that are returned in the same way and assigned using `currentUser = user`

Comment: Are user and currentUser undefined? Or what does it log out when you console.log those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debug I've found the correct way to access the needed informations. Since the user informations after that are retrived are mapped to another object that is the userId, the only way to access to each property is to use a `for` loop. Initially I was thinking that this can be avoided but unfortunately it's necessary otherwise using only dot notation will result in `undefined`. This is how I've solved

```
api.getUserInfo(userId, (err, user) => {
  let username;
  if(err){
   return console.log(err);
  }
  for(var prop in user){
   username = user[prop].name;
  }
  api.sendMessage(`Hello ${username!}`, event.threadID);   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that `api.getUserInfo` is asynchronous.
So you would need to nest them to get it to work.

Or you can try this, since getUSerInfo allows you to add an array of user ids to get the data for:

```
api.listenMqtt((err, event) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  if (event.type === "message") {
    const currentUserId = api.getCurrentUserID();
    const senderId = event.senderID;

    api.getUserInfo([currentUserId, senderId], (err, ret) => {
      if(err) return console.error(err);

      // Ret should contain the two users
      // See: https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api/blob/master/DOCS.md#getUserInfo
      console.log(ret);
    });
  }
});
```

Nesting user calls method:

```
api.listenMqtt((err, event) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  if (event.type === "message") {
    let currentUserId = api.getCurrentUserID();
    api.getUserInfo(currentUserId, (err1, signedInUser) => {
      if (err1) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      api.getUserInfo(event.senderID, (err2, userInMessage) => {
        if (err2) {
          return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log(signedInUser, userInMessage)

        api.sendMessage("...", event.threadID);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: the `ret` object properties are unaccessible and will result in undefined. If you look at the code I've already nested the `sendMessage` inside it but without success...

Comment: Edited the answer with the nesting method. Give that a shot.

Comment: My problem isn't with the user informations to fetch but with the properties of the callback object that is containing it that will be not accessible with dot notation inside the nested `api.sendMessage` method. The `console.log(signedInUser, userInMessage)` will always be logged and give the informations, but I need to access properties of the objects. If you try `signedInUser.name` you will see that it's undefined in console!